# How to retrieve a list of installed packages on (K)ubuntu sorted by category

Tags: linux, ubuntu, package-management, kubuntu, packages

I'm using Kubuntu.
I'd like to get a list of installed packages on my system, and in particular to have them sorted by category, i.e. as seen in Muon Package Manager, in the category filter tab. For a visual reference, it the left part of the window in the following image.

[image]

From inside Muon there is an option to export a list of installed packages in the File menu, but it just exports a plain list (I think that it executes the `dpkg --get-selections` command) and that's not what I'm looking for.

I tried to look in the man pages of `dpkg`, `dpkg-query`, `apt` and `apt-get` but I failed to find any useful information.

The only clue I got is that the manual of `dpkg-query` states that it is possible to sort the output by using some command options, but I haven't found how to sort by category.

Any clue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can indeed do this using `dpkg-query` and a couple of other tools:

```
dpkg-query -Wf='${package}\t${Section}\t${status}\n' | grep installed | 
  gawk '{print $2"\t"$1}' | sort
```

EXPLANATION:

- `dpkg-query -Wf='${package}\t${section}\t${status}\n'` : This command will list all packages (`-W`), as `package name`< TAB >`package section`< TAB >`package status`. From the `dpkg-query` man page:

  ```
  -f, --showformat=format
        This  option  is  used  to specify the format of the output --show 
        will produce. The format is a string that will be output for each package 
        listed.
  ```

  So, this command alone produces output like this:

  ```
  $ dpkg-query -Wf='${package}\t${Section}\t${status}\n' | head
  a2ps    text    install ok installed
  abiword editors install ok installed
  abiword-common  editors install ok installed
  abiword-plugin-grammar  editors install ok installed
  abiword-plugin-mathview editors install ok installed
  accountsservice admin   install ok installed
  acl utils   install ok installed
  acpi    utils   install ok installed
  acpi-support-base   admin   install ok installed
  acpid   admin   install ok installed
  ```
- `grep installed` : selects only those lines describing packages whose status is `installed`.
- `gawk '{print $2"\t"$1}'` : Use gawk to print only the two fields we are interested in (package name and section), to make the output easier to read and sort, print the Section first and the package name second.
- `sort` : Since the section is now the first field, a simple `sort` is enough to sort the packages by section.

The final output looks like this:

```
admin   accountsservice
admin   aptdaemon-data
editors libreoffice-impress
fonts   fonts-telu
games   enemylines3
games   enemylines7
gnome   cinnamon
libdevel    libxmu-dev
libs    libapt-pkg4.12
oldlibs hpijs
python  python-gi-cairo
```

Comment: Thank you, superb answer! It seems that I was looking for a "category" field while it was in fact "section" the option I needed.

Comment: bravo terdon, super cool solution with comprehensive details.